# how to copy locked files ( Device or resource busy error) on windows xp without admin permissions

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, locked-files

Is there is any way I can copy locked files on windows xp machine without having admin rights?
I used unloker tool its great but needs admin rights to install and run.
how it could be done in some programming language like perl/shell/c c++ etc.
or if there exists some workaround for this.

Comment: You might also try asking on serverfault.com and superuser.com

Answer (score 3):

Try this, http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/backupcopy-files-that-are-in-use-or-locked-in-windows/

It should help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it without admin rights

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the backup API, and you need backup privileges to use it. Search MSDN.